# Writing .m class that solve laplace and other stuff

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write m. file that would do the following if I enter this in the command window:

```
>> test
Enter the function: (s^2+6*s+9)/(s^3+2*s^2-s-2)
The Poles:
 -2
 -1
  1

The Zeros:
 -3
 -3

The Result:
1/(3*exp(2*t)) - 2/exp(t) + (8*exp(t))/3

The Initial Value:
  1
```

and here is my attempt: (of course, it doesn't work)

```
function y = f(s)
y = input('Enter the function: ');
[n d] = numden(y);
zeros = solve(n);
poles = solve(d);
yt = ilaplace(y);
disp('The Poles:');
disp(poles);
disp('The Zeros:');
disp(zeros);
disp('The Result:');
disp(yt);
disp('The Initial Value:');
disp(f(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in Matlab work like functions in most programming language: they expect a list of input parameters and return a list of output parameters:

```
function [out1 out2] = myFunc(in1, in2)
```

In your example, the function `f` returns the user input - is that what you want? Also, the input parameter `x` is never used and therefore useless. If you neither use the input parameter, nor the output parameter - then why use a function at all? You could use a Matlab script instead.

In the function body you're using the variable `func`, which has been never defined. What value did you expect it to have? I guess you want to pass the user input to the function `numden`, which expects a numeric or symbolic matrix. You'll have to convert the user input into something that is understood by `numden`. Note that if you want to get the string entered by the user, you'll have to use the Option `'s'` with `input`, otherwise the user input will be interpreted as a Matlab expression.

Comment: All what I need from using the function is to find the initial value f(0), and I edited my code, it is my fault

Comment: Yes, but "f" is the name of the function you wrote, not the one the user gave you, and the return value of your function is "y" which is just the string that the user provided to you. And you have still never used the input value of your function. It was x, then you edited it to s, but in any event you never use that value.

Comment: Make it a script first, not a function. You're possibly mislead by the term 'function'. In Matlab it's a method like in a programming language, not like a mathematical function. Just remove the first line of your code. Then find out what `y` has to look like, so that it is understood by `numden`. When this works, you can think about how you can convert an user input. And when this works you can convert your script to a function, that can be used in other Matlab scripts.